# Немного логики Asp .NET и AngularJS приложения

Tags: клиент-сервер, логика

Доброго времени суток ,стэковерфлоучане, пишу приложение, и задумался над логикой, сейчас я делаю так:

1)Вытаскиваю данные из БД на сервере(к примеру фотографии, которые разбиты на альбомы)

2)Сохраняю все фотографии в массив

3)При клике на определенный альбом - передаю все фотографии и id альбома в метод **ангуляра**

4)Делаю выборку фотографий с нужным **albumId** и возвращаю в массив.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее будет выполнсять эти и схожие дествия с точки зрения логики и безопасности, на стороне клиента или же делать все это на стороне сервера?

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: О какой безопасности идет речь? Каким образом хранятся фотографии на сервере и имеются ли какие-то привилегии у пользователей для просмотра тех или иных фото? Что лежит в базе? О каком методе идет речь, метод с scope(каком?)? Поподробнее...

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Я обобщенно спрашивал, но опишу на своем примере, сами файлы картинок хранятся в папке на сервере, а ссылки на них в БД, пользователи могут только просматривать фото, всю логику приложения(клиентской части) я вынес в Factory, действую только через нее.

Comment: здесь уже стоит вопрос не в том как это выполнять, а на сколько большой объем данных каждый раз будет передаваться от клиента к серверу. К примеру, если у вас в базе 1млн записей с Url фото, то для просмотра 1 фото нецелесообразно передавать все 1млн записей, проще произвести выборку на сервере альбом->альбом->фото(где -> запрос к серверу для получения списка подальбомов или списка фото). Если записей мало, тогда можно отдать одним запросом.

Comment: c точки зрения безопасности значения не имеет, ведь для изменения(повреждения) данных нужно либо управление над процессом выполняющимся на сервере либо доступ к файловой системе каталога вашего хоста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все требования к безопасности по сути сводятся к такому:

1. **Сервер никогда ни при каких условиях не должен отдавать на клиент данные, которые этот клиент не имеет право просматривать.** При этом неважно, если запрос за такими данными на клиенте, запрос всегда может быть подделан. Все проверки прав должны осуществляться на сервере, вся информация должна отфильтровываться в соответствии с правами на сервере. В общем-то всё.
2. **Сервер не должен изменять состояние при использовании get-запросов.** Такие запросы посылаются браузером без проверки кроссайтовой безопасности до запроса и могут быть посланы злоумышленниками (хотя ответ он и не получит, сервер-то запрос обработает).